# Numpy array of numpy arrays with certain format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, syntax

I want to declare a numpy array (`arr`) with elements having a certain format, like this:

```
dt1 = np.dtype([('sec', '<i8'), ('nsec', '<i8')])
dt2 = np.dtype([('name', 'S10'), ('value', '<i4')])

arr = np.array([('x', dtype=dt1), ('y', dtype=dt2)])
```

The structure is something like this:

```
arr['x'] = elements with the format dt1 (sec and nsec)
arr['y'] = array of n elements with the format dt2 (name and value)
```

And the elements within should be accessed like this:

```
arr['x']['sec'], arr['x']['nsec'], arr['y'][0]['name'] etc.
```

But I get an `invalid syntax` error.
What is the correct syntax in this situation?

Comment: Can you explain in words what structure you want your array to have? It's not obvious from your broken syntax exactly what you were trying to do. What shape do you want your array to have? What do you want its dtype to be? How would you access its elements?

Comment: I want the structure to be something like this:
`arr['x']` = elements with the format `dt1` (`sec` and `nsec`)
`arr['y']` = array of `n` elements with the format `dt2` (`name` and `value`)
And the elements within could be accessed like this:
`arr['x']['sec']`, `arr['x']['nsec']`, `arr['y'][0]['name']` etc.
Is it possible to represent it like this? Or is there a workaround this?

Comment: Put that description in your question, with clear formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A doubly compound dtype might work:

```
In [834]: dt1 = np.dtype([('sec', '<i8'), ('nsec', '<i8')])
     ...: dt2 = np.dtype([('name', 'S10'), ('value', '<i4')])
     ...: 
In [835]: dt = np.dtype([('x', dt1),('y', dt2)])

In [837]: z=np.ones((3,), dtype=dt)
In [838]: z
Out[838]: 
array([((1, 1), (b'1', 1)), ((1, 1), (b'1', 1)), ((1, 1), (b'1', 1))], 
      dtype=[('x', [('sec', '<i8'), ('nsec', '<i8')]), ('y', [('name', 'S10'), ('value', '<i4')])])

In [839]: z['x']['sec']
Out[839]: array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)

In [841]: z['y'][0]['name']='y0 name'
In [842]: z
Out[842]: 
array([((1, 1), (b'y0 name', 1)), ((1, 1), (b'1', 1)), ((1, 1), (b'1', 1))], 
      dtype=[('x', [('sec', '<i8'), ('nsec', '<i8')]), ('y', [('name', 'S10'), ('value', '<i4')])])
In [843]: z[0]
Out[843]: ((1, 1), (b'y0 name', 1))
```

A dictionary would work with similar syntax

```
In [845]: d={'x':np.ones((3,),dt1), 'y':np.zeros((4,),dt2)}
In [846]: d
Out[846]: 
{'x': array([(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)], 
       dtype=[('sec', '<i8'), ('nsec', '<i8')]),
 'y': array([(b'', 0), (b'', 0), (b'', 0), (b'', 0)], 
       dtype=[('name', 'S10'), ('value', '<i4')])}
In [847]: d['y'][0]['name']='y0 name'
```

Comment: how could I declare the numpy array of an unknown length?